# Django login page database username is 'master' but i have entered 'e case sensiMASTER' but login was successful

Tags: django-views

Django login page database username is 'master' but have entered 'MASTER' but login was successful want case sensitive for login

do not allow the user if the username in the database is not exactly matches the entered value in the user interface

Comment: Imagine somebody that want to help you. Do you have the impression that with the details you provided, someone can? Please [edit] the question and include enough technical details.

Answer (score 1):

Likely this is due to the [*collation* <sup>[wiki]</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collation) of the database: the set of rules when two values are considered equivalent, and how to order things.

Likely you specified the collation of the entire database as case-insensitive, but at least the `username` column.

You can change the collation of this column, for example in PostgreSQL with:

```
ALTER TABLE auth_user
ALTER COLUMN username
SET DATA TYPE character varying(150) COLLATE "en_US";
```

the query will depend on the database used, but it is always the collation that needs to be changed.